# How to make from-name in email appear with a space using PHP?

Tags: php

I am currently sending text email in PHP and doing something like this:

```
$from = "from: Hike Attendance Update@comehike.com";
$to_email_address = 'some email';
$subject = 'Some subject';
$contents = 'Blah';

mail($to_email_address, $subject, $contents, $from);
```

When I send it, it appears as sent from Hike.Attendance.Update which doesn't look very good.   How can I make it appear with spaces instead of dots?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$from = "from: \"Hike Attendance\" <Update@comehike.com>";
```

I think that's specified in some RFC for email, namely [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the actual name, put the email address in <> chars:

```
$from = "from: Hike Attendance <Update@comehike.com>";
```